# How to handle pandas KeyError in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wrote the following code in a for loop to handle the pandas KeyError I met, but it seemed that I couldn't use a continue statement and except keyword in this block. How could I fix it?

Originally, I would like to raise an exception to show those keys that are not in the table and let the for loop continue while meeting with those KeyErrors.

```
for i in range(1000):

# do something 

 try:
    u= str(df.loc[item_a, 'E'])
    v= str(df.loc[item_a, 'D'])

    w= str(df.loc[item_b, 'E'])
    x= str(df.loc[item_b, 'D'])

 continue

 except KeyError:

 raise Exception('KeyError: {} do not exist in the table.'.format(a))


# do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

If you raise an error, execution will stop. You can put your continue statement in the except block. That will allow you to continue going through the loop. Just make sure to print out/log out whatever information you need before hitting the continue statement.

```
for i in range(1000):

   # do something 

   try:
      u= str(df.loc[item_a, 'E'])
      v= str(df.loc[item_a, 'D'])

      w= str(df.loc[item_b, 'E'])
      x= str(df.loc[item_b, 'D'])

   except KeyError:
      print('KeyError: {} does not exist in the table.'.format(your_variable))
      continue
```

Comment: I got the warning, " 'continue' outside loop" after modifying it. I have checked that the continue statement was aligned with the print statement. How to fix it?

Comment: That sounds like you are not indenting properly. Do you have your code indented like in my answer? Or like in your question? If you have not indented the try and except blocks, you cannot use continue, as that keyword is only applicable inside a loop.

Comment: It seemed that the KeyError could be occurred either in the block "u= str(df.loc[item_a, 'E'])
    v= str(df.loc[item_a, 'D'])"  ,or in  "w= str(df.loc[item_b, 'E'])
    x= str(df.loc[item_b, 'D'])" . How could I catch both of these exceptions? Thanks.

Comment: Since both blocks are under the try, you will catch these exceptions. If what you want is separate messages for both blocks, jut wrap the first two lines in a try-except and then the second two lines in another try-except.